# How to include sidebar with php and use different color for current page in sidebar?

Tags: javascript, php

On my web site every page has the same sidebar which is just a link to every page. Instead of writing the same thing on every page I'm using a file 'sidebar.html' which is then included to every page with php:

```
<?php include 'sidebar.html'; ?>
```

Now I would like to have the name of the current page in sidebar in different colour than any other page name. I have done this with JavaScript like this:
1. get the current page name by the specific id
2. set the new id called 'active' to this name and in css #active gets a new colour

I'm wondering if there is any other solution to obtain the same result and maybe if there is a solution without using JavaScript.

Thank you!

Comment: use a .php file inside, and have PHP generate a small inline `<style>` block that contains your random color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace your `sidebar.html` by a `sidebar.php` file, and simply use PHP variables ; for example, you can define in your current page a variable that represent the current ID, and use it inside your `sidebar.php` to determine which link should be `active`

Answer (score 2):

The other answers suggesting a PHP variable is one way to do this. On the other hand you could do this without using PHP or JavaScript, just pure CSS.

Start by indicating the current page with a class name on your `<body>` tag or other high-level wrapper.

```
<body class="contact-page">
```

Then in your sidebar, make sure each link has a unique class as well. Something like:

```
<a href="/" class="sidebar-home">Home</a>
<a href="/contact.php" class="sidebar-contact">Contact</a>
... and so on
```

Now you can just write CSS classes to do the rest! So if you want your selected links to be blue for example...

```
.home-page .sidebar-home { color: blue; }
.contact-page .sidebar-contact { color: blue; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the html file to a php file and pass a parameter.

Then, in the new `sidebar.php`, get the parameter and define the active class accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

**sidebar.php**

```
$links = array();
$links['page1.html'] = 'Page 1';
$links['page2.html'] = 'Page 2';
$links['page3.html'] = 'Page 3';

$curr_page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

foreach($links as $k=>$v)
{
    echo '<a href="'.$k.'"';
    if($curr_page === $k)
    {
        echo ' class="active_link"';
    }
    echo '>'.$v.'</a>';
}
```

Just wanted to point out that things will get complicated if you put files into sub-directories like this:

```
$links = array();
$links['subdir1/page1.html'] = 'Page 1';
$links['subdir2/page2.html'] = 'Page 2';
$links['subdir3/page3.html'] = 'Page 3';
```